# How do you resize a popup using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I have a bookmarklet that opens a small popup using `window.open()` and have set the width and height on it. Usually when it opens the content is the right size for the window. But there is one specific time where I need to display a bigger piece of content to the user.

How can I use javascript from the page displayed in the popup to resize it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.resizeTo()`. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo)

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.resizeBy()` instead. It's far simpler.

[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892885/788958).

Comment: How is using `resizeBy()` simpler than `resizeTo()`? Both accept height/width params. The link you provided just asserts the same - that the latter is more complicated. Based on the code in that example, it looks 'more complicated' to transform the targetHeight/Width before calling the method.