# cross-browser resize browser window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I would like to be able to resize the browser window with JavaScript. I don't want to use jQuery, and the smaller the code the better, but it has to work in all of the major browsers including Chrome.

Any solutions?

Thanks for the help!

P.S. The tags that this question was tagged with should be combined but I don't know how.

browser -----------same as--> webbrowser

cross-browser----same as--> browser compatibility

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery (or some other useful framework)?

Comment: @Eddie This is just a very small task, and I'd rather not include a very large library.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[window.resizeTo( width, height );](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.resizeTo)

The problem you may face is modern day browsers can prevent you in the settings to not be able to resize the window. There is no way around that.

Chrome will not allow it. [Won't Fix Bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091)

IE is based on [security zones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Because modern day browsers block it. Chrome [won't fix](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091)

Comment: I love how the chrome thread breaks down to flaming like a bunch of children throwing tantrums.

Comment: The article says `resizeTo` is DOM0: general convention not in any standard.

Answer (score 11):

The fact is that Chrome, Firefox and newer IEs doesn't allow resize of tabbed windows and windows not opened by `window.open()` (Chrome at least).

But for popups it's doable for the most part, unless the security setting in the browser blocks that functionality. However using `window.resizeTo()` is complicated. Use `window.resizeBy()` instead.

Chrome has a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35980) getting the size of a popup window to soon so you have to work around that.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1)
    var t = setTimeout("resize()", 200);
else
    resize();

function resize() {
    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var targetWidth = 800;
    var targetHeight = 600;
    window.resizeBy(targetWidth-innerWidth, targetHeight-innerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no way for a web page to resize the main browser window in Chrome. JavaScript code is only permitted to resize popup windows.