# Resize window on loading

Tags: jquery, resize

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.resizeTo(1024,800);
});
```

I'd like to resize the browser window if the site was loaded. 
Whats wrong?

thanks for help

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452040/cross-browser-resize-browser-window-in-javascript some browsers will not allow you to do so. To resize the window for the user is not a good user experience

Answer (score 2):

**You can't resize a window in javascript**. If you can, Imagine a guy running a script like this  :

```
var n = 1 ; 

setInterval(function() {

   if (n++ % 2 == 0) 
   { 
       window.resizeTo(1024,800);
   }
   else 
   {
       window.resizeTo(500,400);
   }

    n = n%2 ; 

}, 20) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN article for `.resizeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.resizeTo):

> 1. You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
> 2. You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

Answer (score 0):

From
[cross-browser resize browser window in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452040/cross-browser-resize-browser-window-in-javascript)

> window.resizeTo( width, height );
>
> The problem you may face is modern day browsers can prevent you in the
>   settings to not be able to resize the window. There is no way around
>   that.
>
> Chrome will not allow it. Won't Fix Bug
>
> IE is based on security zones

So, like Mooseman pointed out, you will have to spawn a new window in order to be able to re-size it.